# Styleguidist with Ant Design: components do not look like supposed

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-styleguidist

I´m using a regular react styleguidist and tried to use it with ant design. But the components are not looking like they are supposed to. I installed antd in the project also.

[Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQBCi.png)

I have not really a clue what could be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include antd(theme) antd.css

import your antd style guide like below in your root component.

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Comment: It improved the styling but it´s still not looking like the original component

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `antd.css` check out [How to import whole antd style](https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#I-just-want-to-use-Menu/Button(etc...),-but-it-seems-that-I-have-to-import-the-whole-antd-and-its-style.) or [How to use in create-react-app](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) docs.

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

Comment: It improved the styling but it´s still not looking like the original componen